# Application running only in Ice-cream Sandwich

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat

I have developed an app in android. It works only in the older android version [ Ice cream sandwich]. It doesn't work in the later versions. Can you please tell me what could be the problem.

Thanks.

Comment: How is it not working in other versions? Is it installing? Is it crashing when trying to run? Does your phone blow up when trying to run? Does it grow legs and run off? We need some more information.

Comment: This is way too broad. For the moment I will vote for this to be closed, but if you can expand your question to indicate exactly what functions which previously worked no longer work, and provide code samples where relevant, there is a chance someone may be able to help you. As it stands you are expecting people to guess what your problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Check this in manifest

```
   <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="21" />
```

This will cover all Android versions. If you want ICS to be your minimum supported version then set your minSdkVersion to 14. API version 21 is lollipop (latest)